# Auto generate MySQL schema based on a CSV file

Tags: mysql, database, csv

I'm trying to import a large CSV file into MySQL database. There will be NO update to the table. So is there a tool (or method) to scan through the CSV file and automatically suggest the most optimal schema? For example, if the length of the longest string of a column is 15, the suggested schema will be CHAR(16). And if a column only contains non-negative integers, the suggested schema will be UNSIGNED.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far ?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of Python tools that I have created might help.

[execsql.py](https://pypi.org/project/execsql/) is a SQL scripting client that will automatically create an appropriate table schema for a CSV file when it is imported (with the [IMPORT](https://execsql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/metacommands.html#import) metacommand), and that can display the table schema that would be created, but not actually import the data, with the [WRITE CREATE_TABLE](https://execsql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/metacommands.html#write-create-table) metacommand.

[chkcsv.py](https://pypi.org/project/chkcsv/) scans a CSV file and reports the number of rows that match different data types for each column in the file.  This is useful for identifying data columns that contain just a few oddball data values that don't match the expected data type.

Other similar tools are probably available in other language repositories.